# Постраничная навигация (Сортировка по дате и времени)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

Есть сайт со статьями. Статьи добавляются на сайт через админ панель. При создании администратор может указать **любую дату и время** публикации статьи. Таблица статей выглядит следующим образом:

[image: Таблица статей]

Как можно увидеть из изображения выше, в содержимом таблицы присутствуют статьи, опубликованные в один и тот же день, но в разное время.

На самой странице вывода статей, сейчас реализована постраничная навигация на php. Для каждой страницы
сейчас выводятся по пять статей используя следующий запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY date, time LIMIT $start, $finish
```

- GET параметр `$_GET['p']` - хранит номер текущей страницы
- `$start` - хранит точку начала отсчета строк в таблице и рассчитывается так: `($_GET['p'] * $finish) - $finish`
- `$finish` - Хранит количество отображаемых статей на странице (В данном случае пять)

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы самые старые (по дате) статьи оказались на самой последней странице. С использованием LIMIT в SQL запросе добиться этого не получается, так как он будет сортировать по дате и времени полученные пять строк для конкретной страницы.

Есть ли для этого какое либо решение на PHP + SQL? Или все же необходимо вывести все статьи без LIMIT, а уже потом обработать постраничную навигацию на frontend, например с помощью JS (включать/отключать отображение нужному кол-во статей).

Comment: с чего вдруг вы решили, что order by применяется после limit ? Если вы хотите чтобы самые старые новости были на самомй последней странице то сортировать надо по убываюнию, а не возрастанию. Также возникает вопрос, зачем при наличии типа datetime вы разделяете дату-время на два поля. одно из них небось еще и varchar какое-нить.

Comment: Интересно, что он уже задавал этот вопрос, и я ему уже указывал на нелепость этой фантазии с лимитом. Но, видимо, он решил, что если задать ещё раз, то факты станут покладистее :)

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо заменить

```sql
ORDER BY date, time
```

на

```sql
ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC
```

Тогда статьи будут отсортированы в обратном порядке.